# Accessing status updates of a user using FacebookClient

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to access a user's statuses with the following code. But it only works if I'm logged into facebook.com. Is it possible without having to be logged into facebook.com?

var FBClient = new FacebookClient("Some long USER access token");
string json = FBClient.Get("FacebookUserID?fields=statuses").ToString();

Answer (score 1):

I guess no, because Facebook User Token works only if this user is connected. Otherwise, this token is expired.

Maybe you have to look out about App Access Token. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). I never used it before.